# Angular Directive that takes a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that can show or hide the element it is on dependent on whether a user has a visibility of a feature:

See [my Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/2s7NlyciU5b6AUB6ZAaY?p=preview)

I would like to apply this directive like below:

```
<div feature="some-feature-name">
   I have the power!
</div>

angular
.module('app', [])
.directive('feature', ['userService' function(){
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel){
          // Logic to work out whether someone is permitted to see that feature

          if(userService.canSeeFeature(featureName){
          }
          // Hides the the element it is on if not.

        }
    };
}]);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This is certainly possible - how do you want to pass the feature to be tested? would it be an attribute on the directive element?

Comment: @Rhumborl Inside the directive link method I would call an external service that has the current user stored inside it and can check whether they have visibility of that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main steps to doing this - getting hold of the feature to check from the attribute and doing the show/hide of the element.

### Getting the feature

The first thing to note is how to get hold of the feature from the attribute

```
<div feature="y">AccessGranted</div>
```

You do this in the using the `attrs` parameter already in the link method. Simply

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
    var theFeature = attrs['feature'];
    var hasAccess = userService.canSeeFeature(theFeature);
}
```

### Hiding the element

Next you need to hide the element if they do not have access. There are a couple of options for doing this.

The "pure Angular" way to do this is to set a variable on your `scope` saying whether the user has access or not, then use [`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) to only show it if the variable is true:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
    scope.hasAccess = userService.canSeeFeature(attrs['feature']);
}

<div feature="y" ng-show="hasAccess">Access Granted</div>
```

However the point of the directive is to do this for you. In this case, I think it is reasonable to use some simple jQuery (more specifically jqLite) to do this in the directive code. If you have full jQuery in your page [`elem.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) is nicer, but jqLite doesn't support this, so you will need to use [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css):

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
    // check for access
    if(!userService.canSeeFeature(attrs['feature'])) {
        // hide the element
        elem.css('display', 'none');
    }
}
```

### Sample

Here is a working sample based on your plunkr:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .service('userService', function() {
    return {
      canSeeFeature: function(feature) {
        // test - only allow access to y
        return feature === 'y';
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('feature', ['userService', function(userService) {
      return {
          restrict:'A',
          scope: {},
          link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel){
            // check for access
            if(!userService.canSeeFeature(attrs['feature'])) {
              // access denied - hide the element
              elem.css('display', 'none');
            }
          }
      };
  }]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Formatters and Parse</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

  <div feature="y">y - I have the power!</div>
  <div feature="n">n - I don't have the power :(</div>
  <div feature="y">y - I also have the power!</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

A modified version of [ngShow](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/4fed66da6c8f1d6d1623cdd21280bfcc9a4b9acc/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js) directive :

```
var featureDirective = ['$animate', 'userService', function($animate, userService) { 
   return { 
     restrict: 'A', 
     multiElement: true, 
     link: function(scope, element, attr) { 
       scope.$watch(attr.feature, function featureWatchAction(value) {
         $animate[userService.isAllowed(value) ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass'](element, NG_HIDE_CLASS, { 
           tempClasses: NG_HIDE_IN_PROGRESS_CLASS 
         }); 
       }); 
     } 
   }; 
 }];
```

Comment: Good idea, It's unlikely that I would need the watcher or animation though as it just needs to hide the element if the service check fails